# Add specific number of days to current date conditionally?

Tags: java, algorithm

So the problem is I have got a date from server and I want to add specific days based on the difference between the current date and the date that I have got from the server.

> serverDate - currentDate

**Working:** This is how I calculate the difference between days,

```
String s=formater.format(currentDate);
long d1 = formater.parse(s).getTime();
long d2=formater.parse(serverDate).getTime();
int totaldays=(int)Math.abs((d1-d2)/(1000*60*60*24));
```

**Working: To make a date added with 5 days from the current date,**

```
    if(totaldays==5)
        {
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
        System.out.println("value of new server date "+c.getTime());
        }

   else if(totaldays==4)
        {
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        System.out.println("value of new server date "+c.getTime());
        }

else if(totaldays==3)
        {
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        System.out.println("value of date "+c.getTime());
        }

else if(totaldays==2)
        {
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
        System.out.println("value of new server date "+c.getTime());
        }

else if(totaldays==1)
        {
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 4);
        System.out.println("value of new server date "+c.getTime());
        }

else if(totaldays==0)
            {
            Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            System.out.println("value of new server date "+c.getTime());
            }
```

**Eventually:** I might need to modify this use case with a **difference of total days to a large number** so, in that case would I need to increase the number of comparisons or is there any trick that I can use to reach a specific date.

Comment: if you do `add(Calendar.DATE. 5-totaldays)` it would save a lot of if/else. and, didn't understand your question....what is your problem?

Comment: do you say that `totaldays` can be a huge number?

Comment: @Kent Basically I want to maintain a gap of 5 days from the date I have got from the server if a gap of 5 days is already there i.e totaldays=5 then I don't need to create a new server date.

Comment: Why don't you use JodaTime? It will make your life easier/

Comment: @ogzd eventualy it could be.

Comment: @pKs, I don't think you clearly explained your requirement. if totaldays is 100, as you said, "the gap is already there (100>5)" you want to add 5 days to serverDate or 100? or 95 or 0?

Comment: @Kent if total days would change : with that the gap will obviously change to 100 in this case then the new gap would be 100 days.

Comment: So what's wrong with what you're doing apart from needing to make the code shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, from the comments of the question, I try to rephrase a bit the requirement:

`totaldays` (gap) is difference between `serverDate` and `currentDate`

- if gap<5, making the gap become 5
- if gap=5, do nothing
- if gap>5, add gap to serverDate

if the what was written above is true

- 1st calculate the `totaldays`

then one line would solve your problem:

```
c.add(Calendar.DATE, totaldays>5?totaldays:5-totaldays);
```

btw, you should clearly describe what you need in your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Use a variable named MAX for example. In your code should go like

```
int max = 5;
```

Then you can do:

```
c.add(Calendar.DATE, max - totaldays);
```

or

```
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5 - totaldays);
```

Comment: I meant a class variable. It would work simply declaring it inside the code anyway.

Comment: @javi You can't do that. You'd then be subtracting too. Not what he needs.

Comment: Why do you say that @Tejaswi Rana? Works fine with his examples :S

Comment: E.g totalDays = 10. What happens? c.add(Calendar.Data, -5). Subtracts 5 days. Is that still correct?

Comment: I think what the author wants is if 5 is something like 300, then there shouldn't 300 if/else or switch.

Comment: @Tejaswi I didn't post the last line of code someone edited mi post :S
Mi original idea was having a variable that you can edit wherever you want.

Comment: Should I re-edit the code if I don't agree or would it be rude. I'm new posting here.

Comment: I think your answer should've been accepted because you wrote it first. Shouldn't have been edited if you used a variable. I am upvoting you.